# removing all elements from xml file except root element c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an xml file

```
<Abc> 
  <image filename="1.jpg" heading="1.jpg" />
  <image filename="10.jpg" heading="10.jpg" />
  <image filename="11.jpg" heading="11.jpg" />
  <image filename="2.jpg" heading="2.jpg" />
  <image filename="3.jpg" heading="3.jpg" />
</Abc>
```

I want to delete all elements except root element. How to accomplish this.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("filename.xml");
doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAll();
string result = doc.OuterXml;
```

But if you know the root node name it is pointless to load the XML and remove all elements. In this case just return the new XML:

```
string newXml = "<rootName/>";
```

Comment: Well, in the last point you'd also have to consider namespaces, xml declarations, comments, attributes, etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAll();
    doc.Save(path);
```

or to keep the attributes on the root:

```
    XmlNode lastChild;
    while((lastChild = root.LastChild) != null) {
        root.RemoveChild(lastChild);
    }
```

Comment: Dear Thank You Very Much I was googling this since long. You have solved my problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: (where `root` is `doc.DocumentElement`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var xml = XElement.Load("xmlfile1.xml");
 xml.Descendants.Remove();
```